# Importing Python modules at MacOS 12.4 from a script

Tags: python

On my MacOS 12.4 is Python pre-installed, in the version Python 3.8.9. I did nothing for that, neither changed pathes.

If I run a Python script, which needs some modules with `import requests` or `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`, I get errors `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ...` - all modules are affected.

But, if I install same modules with `pip3 install bs4`, modules are installed correctly.

What should I change in scripts or Python settings so, that scripts can import modules on usual way?

Comment: Where is the python and pip3 executables? Python is not preinstalled since 12.3, Apple provides does one in Xcode

Comment: Indeed, I installed Xcode devtools before terminal got Python3

Comment: I just tried on a clean setup `/usr/bin/pip3 install bs4` started /usr/bin/python3 and in that `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` and it worked. import requests failed - which is expected as what package is requests? Also where is your pip3